# \addtocontents not writing to the toc file

Tags: table-of-contents

Somehow I can't make `\addtocontents` work.  Here's the MWE (call it `something.tex`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\addtocontents{toc}{whatever}
Lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

And nothing gets written to `something.toc` (even after the second run).  A quick glance at `source2e` confirms that `\@writefile{toc}{whatever}` gets written to `something.aux` - but why then the toc file doesn't even get created?

Comment: You have to issue `\tableofcontents` command.

Comment: OK, thanks!  Why don't you make this an answer?  BTW: I did not issue `\tableofcontents` because I'm writing a class, and I wanted to program the handling of metadata and *writing* to the ToC file *before* implementing the actual table of contents;).

Comment: Actually, it turns out that `\@starttoc{toc}` is enough.

Comment: The class shouldn't (normally) do \@starttoc as that will input the toc and start typesetting before `\begin{document}` has set up all the document defaults.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: thanks, I didn't manage (yet) to look at the source for `@starttoc`.  In my case, the class *will* call it anyway, but my class will also typeset the ToC (in `etoolbox`'s `\AtEndPreamble`).

Comment: OK then you just have to delay writing to the toc to the same hook, if you open it for writing before typesetting it you erase the data collected last time.

Comment: Of course, the `\addtocontents` will be used throughout the document (it's an issue of a journal, and besides the article titles, it will contain "sections", i.e., groups of articles; these groups will have titles in the ToC).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you want to make your explanations into an answer?

Answer (score 2):

You need `\tableofcontents` *after* `\begin{document}` has read the `aux` file, in order to initialise the `toc` file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\AtBeginDocument{\tableofcontents}% in hook so can go in class.

\begin{document}
\addtocontents{toc}{whatever}
Lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Except that `\AtBeginDocument` should not contain typeset material, see LaTeX Companion, 2nd ed. `\AfterEndPreamble` of package `etoolbox` provides a better hook for this.